# BASH if directory contains files or doesn't

Tags: bash, shell

I created a script that executes some commands based on a condition. If directory contains files then run "screen -r" anything else run "screen". Problem is screen sometimes gets executed even when the directory contains files.

```
if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
screen -r
else
screen
fi
```

What I want to do is refine it and break it down into two statements. If directory contains files then run screen-r" & if a directory doesn't contain files run "screen"

```
if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
screen -r
fi
```

&

```
if ["$(directory without files)"] ; then
screen
fi
```

Maybe even a statement that executes based on # of file. If directory contains X amount of files.

Can somebody help me out with this? I hope I explained what I want thoroughly.

Thanks,

Geofferey

Again thank you for all your help, I got it all working now. Here is the final script. It's for the iPhone and an app I'm making called MobileTerm Backgrounder.

```
#Sets up terminal environment? 

if [[ $TERM = network || -z $TERM ]]; then
export TERM=linux
fi

# This script automatically runs screen & screen -r (resume) based on a set of conditions. 

# Variable DIR (variable could be anything)

DIR="/tmp/screens/S-mobile"

# if /tmp/screens/S-mobile list files then run screen -x

if [ "$(ls -A $DIR)" ]; then
screen -x
fi

#if /tmp/screens/S-mobile contains X amount of files = to 0 then run screen -q

if [ $(ls -A "$DIR" | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
screen -q
fi
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find` could be helpful here:

`if [[ $(find ${dir} -type f  | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; then echo "ok"; fi`

**UPD**: what is `-gt`?

`man bash` -> `/ -gt/`:

```
   arg1 OP arg2
          OP is one of -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge.  These arithmetic binary operators return true if  arg1  is  equal  to,  not
          equal  to,  less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to arg2, respectively.  Arg1 and arg2
          may be positive or negative integers.
```

So, `-gt` is "greater than" boolean function.

Comment: Could you explain the -gt option?

Comment: So that would be like if the number of files is grater than 0 so if I wanted a command executed when the directory's files were = to 0 I would us -eq?

Comment: It seems find takes a bit longer to execute.

Comment: Okay I found out how to list the amount of files in a directory ls -A $DIR | wc -l how do I use the boolean? Yours seems formatted differently

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ls` and `wc` this way:

```
if [ $(ls -A "$DIR" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then
   screen -r
else
   screen
fi
```

You have to double quote the `$DIR` variable otherwise you'll have problems with directory names that contains spaces.

Comment: exactly how I was just trying to use the info from other guy :)

Comment: Whats up with the quotes in mine? Notice how my first examples main commands are wrapped in quotes? Why?

Comment: You have to double quote the `$DIR` variable so `ls` see it as a single directory name. Quoting all the "$(...)" doesn't help in this case since `ls` still see `$DIR` as unquoted.

Comment: It fails if there are hidden files in dir.

Answer (score 0):

This seems simpler to me

```
if [  `ls -1q /some/dir | wc -l` -eq 0  ]; then echo "huzzah"; fi
```

The `ls` outputs one line per file and `wc` counts the lines